# What should my Pragma HTTP response header be set to?

Tags: php, http-headers

I have my cache related headers set to expire at eight hours as follows...

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=28800');
header('Expires:' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', strtotime('+8 hours')));
```

With that being the case, what should my Pragma HTTP response header be set to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to set pragma, pragma is set only if you want a no-cache directive. Have a look here for more information: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.32

Comment: My server automatically sets Pragma to no-cache (which I do not have access to change).  So I want to change the pragma value to something more consistent with the cache settings I outlines above, or somehow null out the entire pragma field, all via my php script.  Any ideas?

Comment: if it's apache, it is taking .htaccess into account and have the headers module you can use this directive "Header unset Pragma"

Comment: I don't think the mod_headers.c is activated.

Comment: then it will be difficult to disable the pragma: no-cache. It seems that there is a precedence between Cache-Control and Pragma directive, and that in HTTP 1.1 Pragma is ignored if Cache-Control is set. Have a look at the directive precedence part in this documentation http://www.mnot.net/javascript/xmlhttprequest/cache.html

Comment: What about this: header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=28800, must-revalidate'); header('Expires:' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', strtotime('+8 hours'))); header('Pragma: private');

Comment: You can try, maybe you webserver is not overriding pragma if it is set by the application.

Answer (score 1):

See the PHP doc for [session_cache_limiter](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php). You will see the correct cache headers to send:

public:

```
Expires: (sometime in the future, according session.cache_expire)
Cache-Control: public, max-age=(sometime in the future, according to session.cache_expire)
Last-Modified: (the timestamp of when the session was last saved)
```

private_no_expire:

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=(session.cache_expire in the future), pre-check=(session.cache_expire in the future)
Last-Modified: (the timestamp of when the session was last saved)
```

private:

```
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=(session.cache_expire in the future), pre-check=(session.cache_expire in the future)
Last-Modified: (the timestamp of when the session was last saved)
```

nocache:

```
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```